# Spring boot 2.0.3 thymeleaf Error Rendering some pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I recently upgrade spring boot to the version 2.0.3 and some templates started to fail, I Got this error:

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mypage.html]") 
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: null
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
```

Anybody's faced this issue?

Comment: From which version?

Comment: If you upgraded from version 1.5 to 2.0, take a look on [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#thymeleaf) guide

Comment: There are so many differences between 1.5 and 2.0 that it won't be the first and only one. I am currently migrating my app from 1.5.18 to 2.1.1 and there is a lot to be adjusted. But really... a lot.

Comment: @Jagger you are right, I had to fix the way i was using some th:fields inside a foreach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the way the html was rendering a list for a select component, it had a select inside a th:each like this:

```
<div th:each="lsPassengers, ***stat*** : *{lsPassengers}">
    <select class="e1 populate w-240 tPassengers" name="tPassengers">

    <option th:each="i, ***statPax***: ${session.travelPartner}" 
                            ...
                        </select>
</div>
```

In previous version the variable stat was being used in the loop of the select (dont know why) but it was working before, I changed the reused variable for the another (statPax) and then it started to work again

Hope this helps to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown at runtime whenever you try to modify a collection while iterating over it. Do you have that kind of a situation in your failing views? If so then try this [link](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/java-essentials-preventing-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: It's not my case, This same page was working fine before i upgraded to this version of spring boot, thanks for the reference @Ahmet

Comment: Could you please provide JDK, previous spring boot and thymeleaf versions.